# Java Jtree:how to display selected node

Tags: java

I have a JTree. When i select a node from Jtree , I want to display selected node.

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode selectedNode=(DefaultMutableTreeNode) tree.getLastSelectedPathComponent(); 
type=selectedNode.toString();
```

this code is working perfectly for Left click,but when i use it for right mouse click it wont get selected nor displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try this method?

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {

        int row = tree.getClosestRowForLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());
        tree.setSelectionRow(row);
        popupMenu.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
    }
}
```